# Speeding up matrix entry

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have a bit of a problem with the speed of my matlab calculation. I was able to write a code in matlab to run the calculation for small matrices, but it uses nested for-loops, and with the large datasets I'm using, matlab fails to finish the computation.

Note: I'm not terribly familiar with Matlab, so while the program works, it is extremely inefficient.

In short, I'm trying to create a matrix whose entries describe the relationship between a set of unique locations. As a concrete example, we start with this matrix:

```
B = 

5873 4 1

5873 7 1

5873 1 1

2819 8 2

2819 1 2

9771 4 3

9771 2 3

9771 5 3

9771 6 3

5548 7 4
```

Where the third column is the unique location identifier and the second column is the number of the "segment" that happens to be in the location. Notice that multiple segments can fall into different locations.

What I would like to is to create a matrix that describes the relationship between the different locations. Specifically, for location i & j, I would like the (i,j) entry of the new matrix to be the number of segments that i & j have in common divided by the total number of segments of i & j combined.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
C = zeros(max(B.data(:,3)), max(B.data(:,3)));

for i = 1:max(B.data(:,3))

  for j = 1:max(B.data(:,3))

    vi = B.data(:,3) == i;
    vj = B.data(:,3) == j;
    C(i,j) = numel(intersect(B.data(vi,2), B.data(vj,2))) / numel(union(B.data(vi,2), B.data(vj,2)));
  end

end
```

But it is very very slow. Does anyone have any suggestions for speeding up the calculation?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: What's the typical number of locations and of segments?

Comment: Can you also provide a sample output of what you expect given your above example?  The input is well defined, but what does the output look like?  This is mainly because I want to make sure I understand your problem before trying to solve it.

Comment: Hi Everyone, thank you so much for replying! What I am looking for is a matrix C = [1 .25 .16 .33 ; .25 1 0 0 ; .16 0 1 0 ; .33 0 0 1], which is a symmetric matrix with 1's on the diagonal.

Comment: The datasets that I'm working with a very large. The largest one has 6,418,784 rows with 24,814 unique locations, meaning that the resultant matrix would be of size 24814x24814. Thank you so much for the different approaches provided, and I'm not sure which one would be suitable for a dataset this large.

Answer (score 2):

#### Approach with grouping and loop

1. Locations are grouped according to segments (cell array `groups` in the code below). [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with a custom function is used for the task.
2. A square matrix `C` of size equal to the maximum location is initiallized to zero. For each group, all pairs of locations belonging to that group have their entry in `C` increased by `1`.
3. The matrix `C` is normalized.

Code:

```
groups = accumarray(B.data(:,2), B.data(:,3), [], @(x) {x});  %// step 1
C = zeros(max(B.data(:,3)));                                  %// step 2
for n = 1:numel(groups);
    ind = groups{n};
    C(ind,ind) = C(ind,ind)+1;
end
d = diag(C);                                                  %// step 3
C = C./(bsxfun(@plus,d,d.')-C);
```

#### Vectorized approach using a 3D array

This approach is memory-hungry; and according to @Divakar's comments below, for very large datasets it's not faster than the loop approach:

1. It builds a 3D `logical` array `T` such that `T(m,n,s)` is `1` if and only if locations `m` and `n` share segment `s`. This is done efficiently with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).
2. Summing `T` along the third dimension yields the same `C` as in the previous approach.
3. The matrix `C` is normalized in the same way as previously.

Code:

```
T = full(sparse(B.data(:,3), B.data(:,2), 1));               %// step 1
T = bsxfun(@and, permute(T, [1 3 2]), permute(T, [3 1 2]));
C = sum(T, 3);                                               %// step 2
d = diag(C);                                                 %// step 3
C = C./(bsxfun(@plus,d,d.')-C);
```

---

### Benchmarking

*Credit goes to @Divakar for the following benchmarking and explanations:*

Here are some runtimes comparing the `loop-based` approach against the latter `vectorized` one -

```
***** Parameters: No. of rows in B ~= 10000 and No. of groups = 10 *****
---------------------------------- With loopy approach
Elapsed time is 0.242635 seconds.
---------------------------------- With vectorized approach
Elapsed time is 0.022174 seconds.
 
 
***** Parameters: No. of rows in B ~= 10000 and No. of groups = 100 *****
---------------------------------- With loopy approach
Elapsed time is 0.318268 seconds.
---------------------------------- With vectorized approach
Elapsed time is 0.451242 seconds.
 
 
***** Parameters: No. of rows in B ~= 100000 and No. of groups = 100 *****
---------------------------------- With loopy approach
Elapsed time is 1.173182 seconds.
---------------------------------- With vectorized approach
Elapsed time is 0.464339 seconds.
 
 
***** Parameters: No. of rows in B ~= 100000 and No. of groups = 1000 *****
---------------------------------- With loopy approach
Elapsed time is 10.310780 seconds.
---------------------------------- With vectorized approach
Elapsed time is 54.216923 seconds.
```

One can notice that for the same number of rows in `B`, an increment in the number of groups means a considerable drop in performance for the vectorized approach.

So, this could be kept in mind when choosing the *appropriate* approach for a problem case.

Comment: Finally got chance to run few quick tests with huge datasizes and your loopy approach seems really fast!

Comment: Thanks! I had more hope on the vectorized one, though... :-)

Comment: Oh, you mentioned "_huge_ datasizes". The vectorized approach can't be used there

Comment: Can't be used? Or it would just get slow or run out of memory you mean?

Comment: Yes, I meant it "can't" be used because it requires a lot of memory

Comment: So, ran a quick test with `ncols in B as 100,000` and `number of groups as 1000` and results dictate that vectorized approach is `10x+` slower than your loopy approach.

Comment: So even without memory limitations it's slower? Hm! Well done for JIT, I guess! Maybe that `T = full(sparse(...))` statement is slow. Could you try with `m = max(B.data(:,3)); T = zeros(m,max(B.data(:,2))); T((B.data(:,2)-1)*m +B.data(:,3))=1` replacing that first line?

Comment: Marginally quicker this time, not much really.

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit my answer; vectorized approach is not so fast

Comment: If you are editing, you could mention that this is mostly for huge datasizes! For small datasizes, vectorized approach with `bsxfun` could be better (a quick test suggests the same!)

Comment: When you say "huge", do those datasizes force using virtual memory (disk thrashing)? Or do you mean "huge but smaller than physical memory can hold"?

Comment: Huge as in works and runs fine, just takes more time, that's all.

Comment: I have some interesting runtime results comparing your two approaches. Can I edit your question with it? I would still leave it to you to draw conclusions from it though.

Comment: Actually nevermind, I could paste the runtime text. I did it [here](http://pastebin.com/r10N2f3X).

Comment: Interesting results! Please do edit if you feel like it (I was on my way home and I just saw your comment)

Comment: I would let you do the edit :) Well, you might need to add some text there to explain the runtimes, so would be better if you do I think. The main pattern there is that the vectorized approach is better if the number of groups are on the lesser side.

Comment: Yes, I think it should be you, so that you can explain better

Comment: Check out the edits, if they make sense, didn't try to be too verbose there.

Comment: Perfect! I'll just edit to give you proper credit in the answer

Comment: Or maybe leave it as it is? Because then your avatar would disappear from the bottom of the answer

Comment: Ah.. take your call, I don't care about my avatar under there! :) If you decide to edit, you can add that `N` is the number of rows in `B` ( I missed out on mentioning that).

Answer (score 1):

This could be an approach using one-loop -

```
%// Store column-2 and 3 values in separate variables for easy access
col2 = B(:,2);
col3 = B(:,3);

%// Start and end indices of the groups w.r.t column-3 of B
ends = [find(diff(col3)) ; numel(col3)];
starts = [1 ; ends(1:end-1)+1];

ngrp = max(col3); %// number of groups
intersectM = zeros(ngrp); %// initialize 2D matrix to store intersect counts
for k = 1:ngrp-1

    %// Matches for each group with respect to each other group 
    %// but one less after each iteration
    matches = ismember(col2(starts(k+1):end),col2(starts(k):ends(k)));
    %// OR matches =
    %// any(bsxfun(@eq,col2(starts(k):ends(k)),col2(starts(k+1):end).'),1)'

    %// Store intersect counts
    intersectM(k,k+1:end) = accumarray(col3(starts(k+1):end)-k,matches,[]);
end

grp_counts = histc(col3,1:ngrp); %// counts of group elements

%// Peform numel(intersect)/numel(union)
C = intersectM./(bsxfun(@plus,grp_counts,grp_counts') - intersectM); %//'

%// Since the output is diagonal symmetric, so just copy over the upper
%// diagonal elements into the lower diagonal places
C = triu(C)' + C; %//'
C(1:ngrp+1:end) = 1; %// Set diagonal elements as ones
```